# Rewrite a URL to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The URL I want to rewrite is: `http://domain.com/index.php?name=home` to `http://domain.com/`.

I have created the .htaccess file and put this code for rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^ index.php?name=home [L]
```

But it doesn't work. All requests in my site will redirect to `http://domain.com/`.
Help me to fix this. Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an "end of string" match to your regex:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?name=home [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is generally because of the structure of your page calls , since I dnt know the sources of your files and how you implementet over ftps , you need to organize your pages , there should be a folder called public this folder usually contain your public pages in that .htaccess as well as your script files.